# Which applications can convert multiple CIF files to multiple XYZ files all at once

Tags: python, software-recommendations, cif

I have tried a bunch of apps such as Mercury, OpenLabel but they cannot convert  CIF files to XYZ files in bulk. I am also thinking of doing it in Python but just want to know if there's an app for this. Thank you.

Comment: I have not worked with his program but may be Babel (https://openbabel.org/) is fit for this porpouse.

Comment: While I personally would use OpenBabel `obabel *.cif -O .xyz -m` you could also do this with [`pymatgen`](https://pymatgen.org/usage.html#reading-and-writing-structures-molecules) or [ASE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4781/30)

Comment: If my answer solved your question, could you please click on the tick mark next to it and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ASE

You can use the [ase](https://pypi.org/project/ase/) python library to achieve this.

I tested the following code with 3 CIF files obtained from the Crystallographic Open Data: [1569089](https://www.crystallography.net/cod/1569089.html), [1000017](https://www.crystallography.net/cod/1000017.html), [1000003](https://www.crystallography.net/cod/1000003.html) and it produces their respective XYZ files.

#### Code

```
from ase.io import read, write

# Define the list of CIF files to convert
cif_files = ['1569089.cif', '1000017.cif', '1000003.cif']

for cif_file in cif_files:
    # Read the CIF file using ASE
    atoms = read(cif_file)

    # Define the output XYZ file name
    xyz_file = cif_file.replace('.cif', '.xyz')

    # Write the atoms to the output XYZ file using ASE
    write(xyz_file, atoms, format='xyz')
```